# cannot write binary data in a file using c

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, msdn

I am using vs2010 in an windows vista os the problem is that i want to read and exe file encrypt it and store it but when i write the data back nothing gets inserted i mean the file is created but no errors and the file is empty and i have done it a thousand times and it works on eclipse but not on vs2010 and i need to port it into a gui can anyone please redirect me where i am wrong

```
FILE *pFile, *file;
size_t result;

pFile = fopen(fName, "r+b");
if (pFile==NULL) {MessageBox(NULL, L"Could not open file", L"Information", MB_ICONERROR); return FALSE;}

fseek(pFile, 0 ,SEEK_END);
sData->fSize = ftell(pFile);
rewind(pFile);

sData->fbuffer = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * sData->fSize);
if (sData->fbuffer == NULL) {MessageBox(NULL, L"Memory error", L"Information", MB_ICONERROR); fclose(pFile); return FALSE;}

file = fopen("out.txt", "w+b");
while ((result = fread(sData->fbuffer, 1, sData->fSize, file)) > 0) {
    if (!(fwrite(sData->fbuffer, 1, result, file))) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Write error", L"Information", MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
fclose(file);

//result = fread(sData->fbuffer, 1, sData->fSize, pFile);
//if (result != sData->fSize) {MessageBox(NULL, L"Read error", L"Information", MB_ICONERROR); fclose(pFile); return FALSE;}

fclose (pFile);

return TRUE;
```

EDIT

I am really sorry the problem is with the location of the file it is in unicode format where as fopen accepts ascii and the location only shows C I have to convert it to get the proper result thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use `pFile` instead of `file` in `fread()`.

```
//----------------------------------------------------  pFile not file
while ((result = fread(sData->fbuffer, 1, sData->fSize, pFile)) > 0) {
    if (!(fwrite(sData->fbuffer, 1, result, file))) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Write error", L"Information", MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: @KeshavNair, yes exe file is opened and assigned in `file` not `pFile`.

Comment: sorry i changed it still no luck

Answer (score 0):

I think the file that you are opening for read is not Ascii, so you assumption of calculation of file size based on size of char is wrong.
if you calculate right size of file in bytes and read and write those many bytes you should be fine.

Comment: it is Ascii as i have tested in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You are reading and writing to/from the same file.

> while ((result = fread(sData->fbuffer, 1, sData->fSize, **file**)) > 0) {
>
> if (!(fwrite(sData->fbuffer, 1, result, **file**))) {

Since you just opened this file it reads nothing, so nothing is written as well.

From the man page:

```
w+ or wb+ or w+b
Truncate to zero length or create file for update.
```

Comment: how can I do the same while toggling bits ? for example `pbFile[I] ^= 0x55;` for encryption